# ASP NET C#: How to retrieve value from SDK with multiple levels

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently trying to implement the Microsoft partner center 'Get Order by ID' and I am stuck with getting all the orders for the user that I have entered.

The path that I have to go in order for me to get the orders is

> Items -> [0] -> LineItems -> Order List([0],[1],[2],[3])

Here's my code.

Orders Controller

```
IAggregatePartner partnerOperations = PartnerApplicationConfiguration.GetPartnerCenterTokenUsingAppCredentials();
var customerOrders = partnerOperations.Customers.ById("customerId").Orders.Get();
var test = customerOrders.Items.Select(q => q.LineItems.Select(rq => new
{
  FriendlyName = rq.FriendlyName,
  Quantity = rq.Quantity,
  OfferId = rq.OfferId,
  SubscriptionId = rq.SubscriptionId
})).ToList();
return View();
```

OrderViewModels.cs

```
public class OrderViewModels
{
    public string SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public string OfferId { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Still I am not able to get the all of the orders for that specific user. Any suggestion/help would be appreciated. Thanks!